# Выравнивание картинок в слайдере

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, изображения

Есть HTML:

```
<section class="parallax" >
    <div class="slick-custom">
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/logo/aroma_logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/logo/baj_zdor_logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/logo/dobr_den_logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/logo/f5-logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/logo/logoKosmo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/logo/nova–poshta-logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/logo/podor_logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/logo/stol_juw_logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/logo/tas_logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/logo/wok_logo.png">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="images/logo/zol_vek_logo.png">
        </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

И подключенный JavaScript:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
      jQuery(function($) {
          if ($("#myModalBox") && $("#myModalBox").legnth > 0) {
            $("#myModalBox").modal('show');
          }

            $('.slick-custom').slick({
                  pauseOnHover: true,
                  pauseOnFocus: true,
                  autoplay: true,
                  infinite: true,
                  speed: 20000,
                  autoplaySpeed: 1,
                  slidesToShow: 3,
                  slidesToScroll: 1,
                  cssEase: 'linear'
            });

      });
  });
</script>
```

Как привести картинки к одному размеру (они все имеют разный размер), а также выровнять данные картинки по центру?

PS Bootstrap 2.3.1

Comment: «они все имеют разное расширение» — расширение они имеют одно — PNG.

Comment: прошу прощения, размер (ширина и высота) сейчас исправлю

Answer (score 0):

1. Рабочий код на codepen, jsfiddle или в сниппете ускорил бы получение помощи в разы.
2. Сделайте одного размера блоки `.item`, а картинки внутри впишите в них в желаемом виде с помошью css-свойства `object-fit: contain` или `object-fit: cover` (ну и про `width: 100%;     height: 100%;` не забудьте).